# Why is sql only showing the most recent record?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm a total newbie to sql. I'm trying to pull through ALL the records that correspond with the  shop code, but for some reason sql is only showing me the most recent.
There code i'm using is

```
$currentShopID = 467;
$sql = 'SELECT events.shopID AS ShopID, events.eventID AS EventID
        FROM db1.events AS events
        WHERE events.shopID IN ('.$currentShopID.')';
```

There are 10 records from shopID 467 but it is only showing the most recent one?

Update:
Here is all the code from the function

```
function loadSomeOtherStuff($sids) {
    $currentShopID = implode(',', $sids);

    $sql = 'SELECT events.shopID AS ShopID, events.eventID AS EventID
            FROM db1.events AS events
            WHERE   events.centreid IN (' . $currentShopID . ')';
    $this->_db->setQuery($sql);
    $event = $this->_db->loadAssocList();
    if (is_null($event)) {
        throw new Exception($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
    }

    foreach($event as $row) {
        $this->_dataBySid[$row['ShopID']]['Events']['Shop Code']   = $row['ShopID'];
        $this->_dataBySid[$row['ShopID']]['Events']['Events']   = $row['EventID'];
    }

}
```

Comment: show us the rest of your code. Most likely you're only retrieving the first row of the entire result (which does contain all 10 rows) in your PHP code.

Comment: `loadAssocList()` what does this method do?

Comment: How do you output `$this->_dataBySid`? Did you dump it to see if you get all the dta you need from the database? Try var dumping $event as well. http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Note that you're probably open to SQL Injection.  Unfortunately parameterized queries (usually) don't let you supply an array to an `IN` clause.  Best bet is to essentially bulk-load the data into a temp table and then just join to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty array to show all records

```
 $this->_dataBySid[$row['ShopID']]['Events']['Events'][]   = $row['EventID'];
```